# how to get form post value?

Tags: django, forms

template

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" id="fileform" action="/tools/sw/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <Input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br/>
            <Input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload"><br/>
</form>
```

views:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        req=request.read()
        if 'upload' in request.POST:
            username=jason.loads(req)['username']
            return HttpResponse('upload post')
    return render_to_response('test.html', locals())
```

since my form is not django form, I'm not sure how to get the html "username" 's contont. it seems can't jason loads directly.

Answer (score 3):

`request.POST` is a [dict-like object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) where keys are form field names.  So to to get the form value from the `request.POST` use it like dict:

```
username = request.POST['username']
```

Or, as the more safe version:

```
username = request.POST.get('username')
```